# @angular/common error TS2304 cannot find name 'unknown'

Tags: angular, rxjs, node-modules, rxjs5, rxjs6

I am trying to build an old project but unable to do it because of below errors.Using angular 5.2.9 to build the project but getting these errors.Can someone help

My package.json file looks like this

```
"dependencies": {
 "@angular/core": ">=5.2.9",
 "@angular/router": ">=5.2.9",
 "ng-packagr": "^3.0.6",
 "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2"
 },

  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": ">=5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": ">=5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": ">=5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": ">=5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-server": ">=5.2.9",
    "@types/es6-shim": "^0.31.32",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.40",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^2.53.39",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "tslint": "^4.5.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.4.3",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.22",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.0.0",
    "zone.js": ">=0.7.2"
  },
```

Build is happening but I am getting these warnings when running test cases

```
WARNING in ./~/rxjs-compat/observable/merge.js
Cannot find source file '../src/compat/observable/merge.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../src/compat/observable/merge.ts' in 'D:\MASTERS\master-sales\node_modules\rxjs-compat\observable'
 @ ./~/rxjs/observable/merge.js 6:9-48
 @ ./~/@angular/core/esm5/core.js
 @ ./src/master-sales.service.ts
 @ ./src/master-sales.service.spec.ts
 @ ./src \.spec\.ts
 @ ./spec-bundle.js

WARNING in ./~/rxjs-compat/add/observable/from.js
Cannot find source file '../../src/compat/add/observable/from.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../../src/compat/add/observable/from.ts' in 'D:\MASTERS\master-sales\node_modules\rxjs-compat\add\observable'
 @ ./~/rxjs-compat/Rx.js 24:0-32
 @ ./~/rxjs/Rx.js
 @ ./spec-bundle.js

WARNING in ./~/rxjs-compat/add/observable/fromEvent.js
Cannot find source file '../../src/compat/add/observable/fromEvent.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../../src/compat/add/observable/fromEvent.ts' in 'D:\MASTERS\master-sales\node_modules\rxjs-compat\add\observable'
 @ ./~/rxjs-compat/Rx.js 25:0-37
 @ ./~/rxjs/Rx.js
 @ ./spec-bundle.js
WARNING in ./~/rxjs-compat/add/observable/defer.js
Cannot find source file '../../src/compat/add/observable/defer.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../../src/compat/add/observable/defer.ts' in 'D:\MASTERS\master-sales\node_modules\rxjs-compat\add\observable'
 @ ./~/rxjs-compat/Rx.js 21:0-33
 @ ./~/rxjs/Rx.js
 @ ./spec-bundle.js
```

Comment: Have you tried npm Update command  ?

Comment: @Amey I tried npm update but still it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Please add `"typescript": "3.1.1"` in dependencies as:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "typescript": "3.1.1"
  ...
}
```

*Note: you can use any other version*

Your package.json should look like:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
}
```

Comment: Anshuman thanks It worked..Just one issue I am still getting is "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<UrlSegment[]>' How to fix this

Comment: you will have to import `map` operator as: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'` or `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: I have done that as my reputation is less than 15 so it is not being  publically displayed

Comment: Anshuman I am getting this error while building BUILD ERROR
The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=2.7.2 and <2.10.0 but 3.1.1 was found instead.

Comment: That means you have to install an older version of Typescript.

Comment: @Lokesh use "typescript": "2.9.2"

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal used typescript 2.9.2 but got same error as posted in the question

Comment: @Lokesh I have updated answer update your package.json

Comment: @Lokesh also you are using >= operator for version that will install the latest so you will have to decide first on which Angular version you want to work, it seems you are not configuring your project correctly according to doc for latest version of Angular

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal I tried by taking your package.json also I gave the angular version as 5.2.9 but it did not work

Comment: @Lokesh I have found dependencies related to Angular v5 those are updated in answer. If it stills there create stackblitz or plunker with sample code and share.

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal Build is working fine but the tests are failing because of the above warnings posted in the question.